# Does client also need to call close when the server closes the connection

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp

So, imagine a situation where a client reads from the socket and read returns 0. This means an EOF or that the server has closed down the connection.

Should the client also call close on this file descriptor? If the client doesnt call close does it lead to some file descriptor leaks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you still need to close it.  The handle exists on your machine even if the remote host has closed the connection.

You can still refer to the socket (call various methods on it including `read()` even if the connection itself is closed.  After you call `close()` the handle has completely gone, so calls methods are more likely to cause a segmentation fault than simply returning 0.

To be clear.  Calling `close()` has two actions.

1. It sends the apropriate packet(s) to tell the remote host that the socket has closed.
2. It cleans up memory associate with that socket.

So even when the remote host closes the socket you still need close to clean up the memory.

Comment: So, there is some state in the kernel that still persists in the client when the server closes the connection. So, when the client calls close, is a FIN sent to the server? If yes, then even the server needs to persist some state for that tcp connection until the client calls close.

Comment: Yes, if the socket was destroyed when the remote host closed the connection, then subsequent calls would ask the OS for something that doesn't exist and would crash your application.  So the "socket" must exist until the local application calls `close()` even if the connection is gone.  The connection exists until either the local application or the remote application calls `close()` or some other timeout occurrs.

Comment: Using a closed socket *returns an error code.* It doesn't cause segmentation violations or crash the program.

Comment: Well that's not entirely true either.  Sockets are identified by an [FD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor).  FDs can be recycled so there's no guarantee what will happen.